# Count the occurences of a particular variable inside an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

In my class `Feeds` I have along with other members a member variable called "Date" which is of `String` type. I have an `ArrayList` of `Feeds` objects. I want to find the occurrences of objects which have the same date String. The occurrences can then be put in a `HashMap` that contains the `String` Date as key and # of occurrences as value.

Something along these lines:

```
List<Feeds> m_feeds = new ArrayList<Feeds>();

//add all feeds objects
m_feeds.add(...);

int occurrences = 0;
HashMap<String, Integer> repeatedDatabase = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (Feeds f : m_feeds){
     occurrences = Collections.frequency(m_feeds, f.date);
     // i know this method compares objects but i want to know how 
    // only a single variable can be done
    repeatedDatabase.put(f.date, occurrences);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than giving you a simple solution, I took the liberty of fixing some things in your code please take a look:

```
List<Feeds> mFeeds = new ArrayList<>(); //If you are using Java 7+ you do not need to declare explicitly the Type in Diamonds. If you aren't, ignore this. Also fixed name to adapt to Java standards.

//add all feeds objects
m_feeds.add(...);

HashMap<String, Integer> repeatedDatabase = new HashMap<>(); //See Above.

for (Feeds f : m_feeds){
    String s = f.date; //Suggestion: use a getter method, do not make public variables accessible outside class
    Integer i = repeatedDatabase.get(s);
    if (i == null){
        repeatedDatabase.put(s, 1);
    } else {
        repeatedDatabase.put(s, i+1);
    } 
}
```

Comment: How does this count the repeated entires of date in m_feeds

Comment: It tries to get an Integer from the date Key. If there is one in the map the result will be an Integer, if there isn't one, the result will be null. If it is null, it puts a new Set in the map, if it isn't it adds one to the integer mapped to date.

Comment: @stud91 if you want you can write the if\else statement like this: 

repeatedDatabase.put(s, i == null ? 1 : i+1);

But that's just eyecandy.

Answer (score 1):

Your code will work if you properly overrode `equals` and in the `Feeds` class to return `true` for two `Feeds` instances having the same date (since if you try to put the same key in the Map twice, the new value will override the old value, and since in your case the values would also be the same, it would make no difference). However, each call to `Collections.frequency` would iterate over the entire List, which would give you an O(n^2) time complexity.

One way to make it more efficient :

```
for (Feeds f : m_feeds){
    if (!repeatedDatabase.containsKey(f.date)) {
        occurrences = Collections.frequency(m_feeds, f.date);
        repeatedDatabase.put(f.date, occurrences);
    }
}
```

This would still do more iterations than necessary. It would call `Collections.frequency` once for each unique date, which means you would iterate the List as many times as there are unique dates.

A more efficient implementation will not use `Collection.frequency` at all. Instead, you'll iterate just one time over the list and count the number of occurrences of each date yourself. This would give you an O(n) time complexity.

```
for (Feeds f : m_feeds){
    if (!repeatedDatabase.containsKey(f.date)) {
        repeatedDatabase.put(f.date, 1);
    } else {
        repeatedDatabase.put(f.date, repeatedDatabase.get(f.date)+1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use directly the hashMap?

you can do something like

```
HashMap<String,Iteger> map = new HashMap<>();
for (Feeds f : m_feeds){
    if (map.contains(f.getDate()) { // use the method to get the date
        map.put(f.getDate(),map.get(f)+1);
    else
        map.put(f.getDate(),1);
}
```

I didn't test the code but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

A small update to Angelo's answer..pushing it a bit further.. you can also use a map of string,int[] like this

```
Map<String,int[]> map = new HashMap<>();
int[] countArray = map.get(key);
if(countArray == null)
   map.put(key, new int[]{0});
else
  countArray[0]++;
```

Using the beauty of references :)